# Item is shown outside of the top and bottom when scorlling the QML ListView

Tags: listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

When I scroll ,part of `item` is shown outside of the top and the bottom of the `ListView`.
Looks like below:
The blue area is the `ListView` and the green things is the `Item` 
[image]

I want the `Item` is always in the scope of the `ListView`.

Comment: use [ListView.clip](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop): true

Comment: It works.Thank you very much！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@folibis already answered, but here is link to the documentation property.

Use the `clip` property from `Item` (`ListView` inherits this from `Item`), which [defaults to `false`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop):

```
ListView {
    id: myClippingListView
    clip: true
    //...
}
```